# rich:inplaceInput edit text, refresh component

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a rich:dataTable that contains a rich:inplaceInput component and a several columns

```
<h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">Next Fire</f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{_quartzJobDetails.qrtzTriggerses.nextFireTime}" >
    <s:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short"/>
  </h:outputText>
</h:column>

<h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">Cron Expression</f:facet>
         <rich:inplaceInput layout="block" value="#{_quartzJobDetails.qrtzTriggerses.qrtzCronTriggers.cronExpression}" 
               id="inplaceInput"
               selectOnEdit="true" 
               editEvent="ondblclick">
              <a:support event="onviewactivated" reRender="quartzJb" bypassUpdates="false" 
                        action="#{quartzAction.rescheduleJob(_quartzJobDetails.qrtzTriggerses)}"/>
         </rich:inplaceInput>
</h:column>
```

action method:

```
public void rescheduleJob(QrtzTriggers qrtztrigger){
        CronTrigger trigger;
        try {
            trigger = // boring trigger creation omitted
            this.controller.getScheduler().rescheduleJob(); //boring reschedule omitted
            this.entityManager.merge(qrtztrigger);  //this didn't help any
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            log.error("cron expression incorrect " + e);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            log.error("scheduler no likey " + e);
        }
}
```

When the user edits the inplaceInput with a new cronExpression the "Next Fire" column should be updated with the new time to fire.  This is happening in the database, but the UI isn't updated unless I physically refresh the page.  I've had this problem before, and my best solution involves using JavaScript to refresh the page for me - but that shouldn't be necessary.  So how do I get the data to update without actually refreshing my browser page?
Seam 2.2 Richfaces 3.3.1, JSF 1.2, JBoss 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Is `quartzJb` the id of the table you want to reRender?  If not, just add the id of the table you want to reRender to your support tag:

```
 <a:support event="onviewactivated" reRender="quartzJb,jobTableId" ...
```

Comment: Thanx mbockus, but yes, quartzJb is the table id.

Comment: Is the nextFireTime actually being updated in your action method?  I would try setting a breakpoint on the getNextFireTime() method to see if it's being called when the data table is rerendered.  That might give you some clues on why it's not returning the right value.